# Physical interpretation: weighted eigenvalues of the Laplacian with a potential

Tags: terminology, partial-differential-equations, physics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

*I've already posted this question on Physics.SE, but I thougth it could be useful to ask also here.*

*No problem if moderators will ask me to cancel this thread... But, please, have mercy!* :-D

---

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be a domain and let $V,m:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be two measurable and sufficiently summable functions.

When one considers the eigenvalue problem for the operator $\mathcal{L}:=-\Delta +V$ w.r.t. the weight $m$, i.e.:
$$\tag{P} \begin{cases}
-\Delta u(x) + V(x)\ u(x) = \lambda\ m(x)\ u(x) &\text{, in } \Omega\\
u(x)=0 &\text{, on } \partial \Omega ,
\end{cases}$$
the function $V$ is usually called *potential* and the function $m$ is called *weight*.

Then, *a weighted eigenvalue of $\mathcal{L}$ w.r.t. $m$* is any number $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. (**P**) has at least one nontrivial weak solution $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, i.e.:
$$\forall \phi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega),\quad \int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot \nabla \phi\ \text{d} x + \int_\Omega V\ u\ \phi\ \text{d} x = \lambda\ \int_\Omega m\ u\ \phi\ \text{d} x\; .$$

My questions are:

> 1. Is there any reasonable physical interpretation of those eigenvalues? And what is it?
> 2. Why have the functions $V$ and $m$ those names?

Moreover, I heard that the $p$-laplacian (i.e., $\Delta_p u := \operatorname{div} (|\nabla u|^{p-2}\ \nabla u)$, which reduces to the usual laplacian when $p=2$) can be used to model nonlinear elasticity or something like that; therefore I have also the following question:

> What about any possible physical meaning of the nonlinear weighted eigenvalues coming from the problem:
>   $$\tag{Q} \begin{cases}
> -\Delta_p u(x) + V(x)\ |u(x)|^{p-2}\ u(x) = \lambda\ m(x)\ |u(x)|^{p-2}\ u(x) &\text{, in } \Omega\\
> u(x)=0 &\text{, on } \partial \Omega ,
> \end{cases}$$
>   where $1 < p < \infty$?

Many thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: In the linear case, the spectrum of $-\Delta + V(\cdot )$ is strictly connected to the study of standing waves for Schrödinger equations. There are hundreds of papers about this. For the $p$-Laplace operator, the problem is nonlinear and mostly open. As far as I know, it is chiefly a mathematical problem.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66418/on-the-physics-background-of-p-laplacian-equation

Comment: @Siminore : Do you know if there is any paper about sufficient conditions for the first eigenvalue of $-\Delta +V$ to be $> 0$?

Comment: You could start from these lecture notes. Some conditions are hidden there :-) http://www.math.nsysu.edu.tw/~amen/posters/pankov.pdf

Comment: I'm absolutely going to take a look at those notes! Thank you.

Comment: Theorem 8.17 in the above notes says $-\Delta+V$ is symmetric for $V \in L^2+L^\infty$ on the domain of $\Delta$. So, at least it doesn't have negative eigenvalues. This makes sense in terms of springs and masses - if the eigenvalue is negative, the acceleration would be in the same direction as the position so the system would blow up.

Comment: Cross-listed from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31100/2451

Answer (score 6):

The left hand side $-F=-\Delta u + Vu$ models force in a material where points try to pull their neighbors towards their local value in a spring-like manner, but also get pulled down by an external force that increases linearly with displacement (for example, other springs or long range gravity).

Now suppose $m$ is understood as a mass (density), and consider Newton's law $F=ma=mu_{tt}$. We see that solving $-\Delta u + Vu=\lambda m u$ is finding modes such that 
$$-u_{tt}=\lambda u.$$
In other words, modes that will stay the same shape, but simply grow (complex-)exponentially in time.

Here is a 1-dimensional diagram:

[image]

**Edit:** To clarify, the extension to the p-laplacean, $\nabla \cdot |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u=\nabla \cdot k(u,x) \nabla u$ models a material where the force of molecules pulling on their neighbors is p-nonlinear in the displacement gradient. In other words, the "springs" in the above diagram are not ideal.

Comment: Great! Thank you Nick.